# Infinite Catalan Sum involving polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I was solving this problem:

Given a coin that lands on heads with $p$ probability, what is the probability that a series of coin flips will end with exactly one more head than tail? For instance, H and THTHH are examples of such sequences. I was able to reduce this problem to the following answer in the form of an infinite series.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n p^{n + 1} (1 - p)^n
$$
I pop this into Wolfram and it spits out $\frac{p}{1-p}$.
My question is: How do I prove this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The expression $\frac{p}{1-p}$ takes all possible non-negative values for $p \in [0, 1)$, so that can't be the probability.

Comment: Right, sorry. It's only valid for $|4-4p||p| < 1$ according to Wolfram.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to prove.  Obviously if the coin is flipped an odd number of times for this probability of the event to be positive.  Among the (odd?) numbers, are you specifying some way to select the number of times the coin is flipped?  Without that it seems ill defined.

Comment: BTW, $p(1-p) \leqslant \frac14$ for any $p \in (0, 1)$ so that doesn't say anything much, Sammy Black's comment remains valid.

Comment: Whoops, seems Wolfram was wrong about that. I’ll elaborate more on the question. I will keep flipping the coin until I reach a sequence with one more head than tail. If $p$ is low enough, I may never stop flipping.  Therefore it only makes sense that $p < \frac{1}{2}$, so this sum is really only defined for those values, which turn out to span 0 to 1.

Comment: The sequence can only be terminated at the odd naturals, and the number of terminating sequences are the Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows by taking the well-known generating function for the Catalan numbers,
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}C_n x^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},
$$
and setting $x\gets p(1-p)$. For a proof of the above, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof.